# RTMP loading test with JMeter

Tags: flash, jmeter, load-testing, live-streaming, axshockwaveflash

I have used JMeter to perform some loading tests on my company. Now we need to test an live stream service, but I don't know how to do that. I've made a good research so far and got nothing.

The stream is send as flash application, the type is `x-shockwave-flash`.

Are JMeter able to handle with RTMP? If no, what is a good alternative?

[image]

Comment: I never tried this before- check this- https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-http-live-media-streaming-hls-jmeter

Comment: @VinothS Well, as I have understood by that link, JMeter is able to test only HLS protocol, but in my case is probably RTPM (I don't have sure, but since the application type in chrome show shockwave-flash, I think that must be RTPM). Anyway, I'm still in search, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't support `RTMP` natively but you can write your own sampler by extending the `AbstractSampler` and using a third party RTMP library for Java, such as Red5 to handle the connection.

For the latter, you can find an example plugin here: 
https://github.com/taktod/RtmpPluginForJmeter

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will see what this project can help me.