# Load testing with JMeter for FLV live streaming

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, live-streaming, flv

I am doing a FLV live streaming load testing with JMeter, however, I didn't manage to find any JMeter FLV plug-ins.

I found the below in stackoverflow, but the url of the answer is inaccessible.
[RTMP loading test with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978728/rtmp-loading-test-with-jmeter)

Anyone can share their experience on how to do load testing for FLV live streaming?

Answer (score 0):

FLV stands for [Flash Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) which supposed to be rendered and displayed by the browser plugin like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flash-player-%20/fnipglnbhfacfmefbgiiodalehbcgcbm?hl=en)

When it comes to JMeter simulation it's sufficient to just [download](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter/) the file issuing simple single GET request using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler followed by [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to introduce the relevant "sleep" time to mimic the user "watching" the video.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Our case is slight different as we are using the live streaming http-flv protocol (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071489/how-to-play-live-flv-stream).